# how can i add a line break in XML

Tags: html, xml, linkedin-api

hi i am working with linkiedin api , there i have a xml

```
function send_messeges($access_token, $xml_atring) {

    $profile_url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox";
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <mailbox-item>
          <recipients>                
            ' . $xml_atring . '
          </recipients>
          <subject>'.$this->send_subject.'</subject>
          <body>'.$this->send_message.'</body>
        </mailbox-item>';
    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $access_token, "POST", $profile_url);
    $request->sign_request($this->method, $this->consumer, $access_token);
    $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");
    $response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "POST", $xml);        
    return $response;

}
```

in

```
$this->send_message
```

i have a message , i want to  add some HTML with message , but linkedin API does not allow me to do that .

even the

```
<![CDATA[
        Line 1 <br />
        Line 2 <br />
        Line 3 <br />
        ]]>
```

is not working here , `so is there any built in xml tag i can use for line breaks ansd is there any tags equalant to HTML tags` . please help

**UPDATE**

if i use message

```
"Elephanti <br/> invitation Message, Visite our site http://elephanti.com";
```

the response is

```
Invalid xml {Element not allowed: br@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 in element body@http://api.linkedin.com/v1}
```

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara nop,  what is the use of that , can you please explain

Comment: Simply add &#xD; where you want a line break :)

Comment: no in linekin api ,adding &#xD is invalid :( .  so is there any pre defined xml tags equalant to html tags in API . like <br> == <linebreak>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&#xD` in your XML document wherever you want to have the line breaks.

There's a good explanation at this site: http://www.stylusstudio.com/xmldev/200309/post80050.html

**ANOTHER OPTION**

Try just typing `<br/>` where you want the space

**EDIT FOR FUTURE VIEWERS**

What worked for him was typing `\n` where he wanted the line-break

Comment: no it is not adding &#xD is invalid in the API . so is there any pre defined xml tags equalant to html tags in API . like <br> == <linebreak>

Comment: try the other option: using <br/> *dont forget the / before the closing tag

Comment: well than you probably can't make a linebreak in your case because these are the only options for line break in xml. **i just thought about it you should maybe try writing `\n` where you want a line break

Comment: yep , i tried with \n , and it worked  thank you very much :)